# Spring AMQP Notification/Events on SimpleMessageListenerContainer, when queue gets deleted

Tags: java, spring-amqp, spring-rabbit

I have a scenario where I am consuming messages from queues using `SimpleMessageListenerContainer`. When any of these subscribed queues got deleted, I would like to get notification or events.

```
SimpleMessageListenerContainer simpleMessageListenerContainer
        = new SimpleMessageListenerContainer(cachingConnectionFactory);
simpleMessageListenerContainer.setQueueNames(
        "testQueue1","testQueue2","testQueue3");
simpleMessageListenerContainer.start();
```

Answer (score 1):

There is currently no event published when a consumer is cancelled due to a queue being deleted, aside from logging a WARN log.

Feel free to open an [Improvement JIRA Issue](https://jira.spring.io/browse/AMQP) and we'll see if we can get something into the upcoming 1.5 release.

In the meantime, you could possibly hook into your logging subsystem (e.g. configure a custom appender), or even one of the AMQP appenders provided by the framework for log4j and logback and have a consumer on the logger queue look for the consumer cancelled log.