# spring-amqp detect ConnectException

Tags: spring-amqp

How can i detect this exception when i start my application:

```
org.springframework.amqp.AmqpConnectException: java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
```

The project is configured in the Spring way (http://projects.spring.io/spring-amqp/) and I can see the errors in the logs, but I can't detect it in my java Classes.

```
Consumer raised exception, processing can restart if the connection factory supports it. Exception summary: org.springframework.amqp.AmqpConnectException: java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
Restarting Consumer: tags=[{}], channel=null, acknowledgeMode=AUTO local queue size=0
Failed to check/redeclare auto-delete queue(s).org.springframework.amqp.AmqpConnectException: java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.support.RabbitExceptionTranslator.convertRabbitAccessException(RabbitExceptionTranslator.java:54)
at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.AbstractConnectionFactory.createBareConnection(AbstractConnectionFactory.java:217)
at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.CachingConnectionFactory.createConnection(CachingConnectionFactory.java:444)
at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.ConnectionFactoryUtils$1.createConnection(ConnectionFactoryUtils.java:80)
at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.ConnectionFactoryUtils.doGetTransactionalResourceHolder(ConnectionFactoryUtils.java:130)
at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.ConnectionFactoryUtils.getTransactionalResourceHolder(ConnectionFactoryUtils.java:67)
at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitTemplate.doExecute(RabbitTemplate.java:1035)
at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitTemplate.execute(RabbitTemplate.java:1028)
at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitTemplate.execute(RabbitTemplate.java:1004)
at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitAdmin.getQueueProperties(RabbitAdmin.java:254)
at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer.redeclareElementsIfNecessary(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:947)
at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer.access$300(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:82)
at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageProcessingConsumer.run(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:1065)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.connect0(Native Method)
at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(DualStackPlainSocketImpl.java:79)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:339)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:200)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:182)
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:172)
at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:579)
at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.FrameHandlerFactory.create(FrameHandlerFactory.java:32)
at com.rabbitmq.client.ConnectionFactory.newConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:615)
at com.rabbitmq.client.ConnectionFactory.newConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:651)
at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.AbstractConnectionFactory.createBareConnection(AbstractConnectionFactory.java:208)
... 12 more
```

This can happen for example when you have no access to the AMQP port.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is currently no event emitted when this error occurs (I have created a [JIRA issue](https://jira.spring.io/browse/AMQP-509) to add one.

In the meantime, since the the connection is shared, you could call `createConnection()` on the connection factory from your own code from time to time, to check the connection state.

Or, you could hook into the logging subsystem to capture the WARN log, as I described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30988483/spring-amqp-notification-events-on-simplemessagelistenercontainer-when-queue-ge/30989728#30989728).

Comment: Thanks Gary, it's ok for now.